# reading a file structure from text file php

Tags: php

I am ,net programmer but as I am studying master degree and I have a task in PHP to create a TEXT FILE WITH THE ABOVE FILE STRUCTURE AND READ AND INSERT INTO THE DATABASE .

**

```
Documents
   Images
      Image1.jpg
      Image2.jpg
      Image3.png
    Works
      Letter.doc
      Accountant
           Accounting.xls

Program Files
     Skype
         Skype.exe
         Readme.txt
     Mysql
         Mysql.exe
         Mysql.com
```

My solution is I created a text file with this content

```
01dDocuments
11dImages
111fImages.jpg
112fImage1.jpg
113fImage2.jpg
12dWorks
121dAccountant 
1211fLetter.doc
02dProgramFiles
21dSkype
211fSkype.exe
212fReadme.txt
22dMysql
221fMysql.exe
222fMysql.com
```

AT first I try to get the directory and their parrent directory right - the problem is the nest folders like 'Accounting' and I cannot think of a better solution. Thanks for any help

```
 WalkDirectoryTree( 0, 1); 

            function WalkDirectoryTree(int $parrentcategory,int $root)
            {


               $file = fopen("testt.txt","r");
               while(! feof($file))  
               {
                 $row = fgets($file);                   


                if( mb_substr($row, 0, 3) == $parrentcategory.$root.'d')
                {

                 $dir = new DirectoryFile();           
                 $dir -> setName($row);   
                 $dir-> setParrentId($parrentcategory);               
                 print_r ($dir);
                 echo "<br>";
                 WalkDirectoryTree($parrentcategory, $root+1);
                 $parrentcategory++;    

                 }


               }
                   fclose($file);


            }

           include('../master.php');

?>
```

Comment: Would a YAML file resemble the original file more and ease the file reading part?

Comment: I think this would work just by using hyphens to declare the depth of the folder/file so you would have `--Acountant` you could then figure out based on the current depth (amount of hyphens). Probably not allowed by your task, but I also suggest just using a JSON file and then you can simply do `json_decode($file, true)` and you get the structure back as an array.